# How to get new tab/link opened on the right of the current tabs in Chrome web browser?

Tags: google-chrome

Currently when a new link is opened, the new tab is opened next to the **current tab**.

What I need is that it should appear next to the **last tab** instead, as seen in the snapshot below (position #2 is what I want, rather than #1).

How can I get that in Google Chrome?

[image]

Comment: When I open a new tab in Chrome it appears at position #2.  I am using Chrome Version 32.

Comment: @Devid Chrome uses some heuristics to determine where it should open - sometimes it opens right next to the current tab, sometimes at the end

Comment: @Sathya Not exactly. The only two possible target position are "to the right of the current tab" and "to the right of the last opened tab". The former condition is true if you open multiple links into new tabs in a row. A tab is (by default) never opened on the far right, unless it happens to follow from one of the two other rules.

Comment: Due to security reasons, I try to avoid installing extensions if I can. Here's a simple workaround: On the current page, find a link you can trust. Simply right click and open it in a new tab. It's not the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done.

Comment: All extensions worked like a charm but with a new tab group function it doesn't open tab in current group but move the tab at the end of all tabs. I would like to open a new tab at the end of current group.

Comment: Yes, the "next tab" extensions ruin the tab groups

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[TabsPlus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabsplus/nikomkkhhpfoeamojhhgpfkpkdlfhfii) gives you the option to select where you want a new tab to open - selecting "last" will result in the behaviour you want.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for multi-windows. For multi-windows see @Louis 's answer https://superuser.com/a/943967/160570

Answer (score 9):

(TabsPlus is not working sometimes)

Try [Tab Position Options](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-options/fjccjnfkdkdmjohojoggodkigkjkkjhl/related?hl=en)

> Tab Position Options empowers the user to select the tab order.
>   It is possible to select the tab opening position, the new tab behavior and the behavior after closing a tab in the Chrome browser.
>
> #### Available options
>
> - Activate Tab After Tab Closing
> - New Tab background
> - Open pop-up window as new tab
> - External Links in New Tab

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Comment: I have Chrome version 54.0.2840.99 and TabsPlus does *not* work.  The latest TabsPlus is version: 8.8.5 and updated: June 23, 2013.  Thanks for the hint, Tab Position Options 5.6 works great with this Chrome version

Comment: Tab Position Options doesn't work well with tab groups in Chrome 95.0.4638.69. Basically it can't handle putting groups back they way they were if you restart your computer. Almost all tabs will then be outside your groups

Answer (score 7):

I use [Tab Position Customizer 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-customizer-2/jglbflnkbgbklegdblkohbbbheeeklej?hl=en) for this. When you bring up the options for this extension, the first set of options, titled "Tab Opening Position" allows you to set where new tabs open.

I've tried TabsPlus, which is recommended by the [currently accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/693687/282039) but found that it does not work with multiple windows.

I've checked Tab Position Options, which was recommended by [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/836998/282039) but I did not like the fact that it required the ability to read and change data on the pages I visit *in addition* to requiring the ability to read browsing history. Tab Position Customizer 2 only needs the ability to read browsing history (same as TabsPlus).

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on your `Tab Position Customizer 2` link. I can't find it on the app store either, only `Tab Position Customizer - Modified`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't like any of the extensions suggested because they all changed the default behavior, when I was looking for solution that allowed me to open a new tab either on the far-right (the default behavior) or to the right of the active tab (the new behavior).

Found a solution that worked better for me [here](http://ladyalys.blogspot.com/2011/08/chrome-tip-open-new-tab-next-to-current.html) -- adding a Chrome search engine shortcut to a simple javascript command:

```
javascript:window.open();
```

Comment: Please explain how a user would do this and use it.

Comment: This is the method of choice. You don't need to install any extension.

Comment: Don't think OP asked about explicit new tab. Its more like when you right-click and select 'Open link in new tab' or press mouse-wheel on a link.

Answer (score 1):

[The 'New Tabs At End' plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tabs-at-end/bgogjfbkjgjhonhikkkflpkgpcpfljoa) forces new tabs to open at the end of the tab strip.

New Tabs At End makes all of your new tabs open at the end of the tab strip, much like how Firefox's tabs work.  When you close a tab, it selects the next tab in the strip, much like how Firefox's tabs work.